# Increasing peers in MCSession decreases transfer speeds drasitically

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipeer-connectivity

I am building an presentation app which uses Multipeer Connectivity framework and shares data through WiFi only.
I observed that while sharing resources with peers using

> sendResourceAtURL:withName:toPeer:withCompletionHandler:

data transfer speed decreases drastically when peer count goes up. How can I overcome this?

Secondly how would I get to know that weather infrastructure WiFi or iPad peer-to-peer WiFi is being used by framework to transfer data?

Answer (score 0):

My experience with MPC has been similar. The more peers you connect and, more importantly, the more data you send between the peers, the slower it all gets.

The only solution I have been able to come up with is to transfer the data to a third party (such as Amazon S3) over WiFi/cellular, and then pass the URL to that uploaded data to the peer. Depending on what you are attempting to do with MPC this may defeat the purpose, but it seems that MPC was not built to transfer large amounts of data.

To answer your second question, there is currently no way to find out what technology the framework is using.